# Live Wallpaper crash when tap on Settings

Tags: java, android, crash, live-wallpaper

allways when i tap on *Settings...* button in Live Wallpaper Picker it stop. And then stop my Live Wallpaper too.

[image]

Can you help me?

**wallpaper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:thumbnail="@drawable/ic_bubbles"
android:name="@string/app_name"
android:description="@string/app_name"
android:settingsActivity="com.chovanec.bubbles.Settings_activity"/>
```

**Settings_activity.java**

```
package com.chovanec.bubbles;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Settings_activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("activity onCreate", "");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**settings_layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Hello, world!"
        tools:context=".Settings_activity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.chovanec.bubbles"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.2">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bubbles"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <service android:label="Bubbles by MCh"
        android:name="Bubbles"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />

        </service>

    </application>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />
</manifest>
```

**LogCat**
here is logcat

```
01-11 10:57:37.990: E/Trace(1960): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-11 10:57:38.150: D/gralloc_goldfish(1960): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-11 10:57:57.801: E/SurfaceTextureClient(1960): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
01-11 10:57:57.801: E/SurfaceTextureClient(1960): queueBuffer (handle=0x2a1099b0) failed (No such device)
01-11 10:57:57.801: D/AndroidRuntime(1960): Shutting down VM
01-11 10:57:57.801: W/dalvikvm(1960): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Native Method)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at com.android.internal.view.BaseSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(BaseSurfaceHolder.java:215)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at com.chovanec.bubbles.Bubbles$BubblesEngine.draw(Bubbles.java:116)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at com.chovanec.bubbles.Bubbles$BubblesEngine.access$0(Bubbles.java:68)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at com.chovanec.bubbles.Bubbles$BubblesEngine$1.run(Bubbles.java:50)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-11 10:57:57.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1960):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 10:58:00.360: I/Process(1960): Sending signal. PID: 1960 SIG: 9
01-11 10:58:05.590: E/Trace(1994): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-11 10:58:05.920: D/gralloc_goldfish(1994): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-11 10:58:32.749: D/dalvikvm(1994): GC_CONCURRENT freed 47K, 2% free 8356K/8455K, paused 73ms+42ms, total 271ms
```

Comment: Please post the logcat output

Comment: where is your `WallpaperService` service , have you added `android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER` permission ? if not then see [vogella AndroidLiveWallpaper](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html) tutorial .Thanks

Comment: yes, BIND_WALLPAPER permission is added in manifest

Comment: show your manifest file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to declare your activity in `manfiest.xml`

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings_activity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:exported="true" />
```